# mp3info giving an error with variable filename

Tags: python

I have been using mp3info to calculate my file length using the following syntax:

```
 mp3info -p "%S" /path/to/file
```

whenever I use the code with the filename I get the correct output:

```
 mp3info -p "%S" far_from_love.mp3
```

However, on storing the filename in a string variable and then using the variable I get an error:

```
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could anyone tell me how to correctly use the command with a variable filename?

this is the python code which uses mp3info

```
listing=os.listdir("C:\\Python27")
for f in listing:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(f,'*.mp3'):

         ext=f[:-4]                             #extract name of file without extension
         WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME="%s.wav"%ext
         print WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME#save output filename as wav extension
         print f
         x=os.popen('mp3info -p "%S" f).read()
         print x
```

Comment: Please also include the relevant Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=os.popen('mp3info -p "%S" f).read()
```

is missing a closing quote:

```
x=os.popen('mp3info -p "%S" ' + f).read()
```

You may also want to use the safer [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
import subprocess
x = subprocess.check_output(['mp3info', '-p', '%S', f])
```

Comment: thanks a lot! that solved my problem,i got the syntax of adding f wrong (didn't use +f)